# Selecting Value from Last Child of an XML file

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am parsing an URI for query_id. I want to get the last query's id. That is actually the last added node in the URI.

I am using the following code but it is failing to return the last node but is returning info from the first node. HELP !!!

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("helpdesk.hujelabs.com/user.php/1/query");
XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNode id = node.LastChild.SelectSingleNode("//queries/query/description/text()");
string TID = id.InnerText;
```

Comment: I dont know how to put code here but this is what i am using...


XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("http://helpdesk.hujelabs.com/user.php/1/query");
XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNode id = node.LastChild.SelectSingleNode("//queries/query/description/text()");
string TID = id.InnerText;

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the only correct solution at present, explaining this FAQ and providing a complete, simple and easy solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Any answer of the form**:

```
//queries/query[position() = last()]/query_id/text()
```

**or**

```
//queries/query/description[last()]/text()
```

**is wrong**.

**It is a FAQ**: The XPath `//` pseudo-operator has lower precedence then the `[]` operator -- this is why the above expressions select any `query` (or respectively `description`) element that is the last child of its parent -- these can be all `query` or `description` elements.

**Solution**:

**Use**:

```
(//queries/query)[last()]/query_id/text()
```

**Also note:** The use of the `//` pseudo-operator usually results in signifficant loss of efficiency, because this causes the whole (sub) tree rooted at the current node to be completely traversed (O(N^2) operation).

**A golden rule**: Whenever the structure of the XML document is statically (in advance) known and stable, never use `//`. Instead use an XPath expression that has a series of specific location steps.

For example, if all the elements you want to select can be selected using:

```
 /x/y/queries/query
```

**then use the above XPath expression** -- not `//queries/query`

Comment: @svick: You don't know the structure of the XML document and it is likely that its top element isn't named `queries`.

Comment: @Dimitre, acutally, I do know it, the URL in the question works.

Comment: @svick: I wasn't aware there had been any URL in the question.

Answer (score 1):

use this XPath

```
 //queries/query/description[last()]/text()
```

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve last query's `query_id`, change your XPath to

```
/queries/query[position() = last()]/query_id/text()
```

Or alternatively, use LINQ to XML:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("http://helpdesk.hujelabs.com/user.php/1/query");
var elem = doc.Root.Elements("query").Last().Element("query_id");
var TID = (int)elem;
```